# How to verify city

Tags: jquery

I would normally use:

```
        if ($("#parkState").val() == "0") {
            alert("Please select a state.");
        }


<option>Select a city</option>
<option>city1</option>
<option>city2</option>
<option>city3</option>
```

But I have no values here. How can I test my if statement against "Select a city"?

Comment: Although you can use `.text()` get the text , why not use values?

Comment: You could either assign arbitrary values and validate against them or it is possible to validate against the text. The first approach for instance you could assign a value of -1 and if you see that value you know they haven't selected a city.

Comment: I don't have `<option value="1"></option>` in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('#parkState option:selected').text()` to get the `Select a city`

```
if ($('#parkState option:selected').text() == 'Select a city') {
  alert('Please select a state.');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `index`, as it'll still work even when you change the text:

```
if ($('#parkState :selected').index() == 0) {
  alert('Please select a state.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `selectedIndex` property of the `select` element. Try this.

```
if($("#parkState")[0].selectedIndex == 0){
    alert('Please select a state.');
}
```